# How to serve React bundle.js with Traefik Ingress Controller?

Tags: reactjs, go, kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have a Golang/React app deployed on Kubernetes. One of the prefix paths my app uses is `/staging`. However, every time I try to access my app at `hostname.com/staging` I get an error 404 in the dev console saying it could not load bundle.js. Is there a configuration I need to take care of in React or is it something in my Golang server? Do I need to use React Router?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand your case, but can clarify some moments: you don't need to have `react-router` in case of no internal routes in your react application. Overwise, if you have internal routing, there is a tricky way how to serve your application and split your URL of env and the internal route. Traefik can be a reverse proxy and application should serve itself (e.g. be build in nginx-based docker image).

Comment: Could you please share your Traefik Ingress yaml configuration file? Could you please check if it is working on the `/` path instead of `/staging`? Are the pod from your app are running properly?